# How to access Struts DynaValidatorForm properties form JSP

Tags: jsp, struts

I have a struts action which populates a field.

```
public ActionForward appForm(ActionMapping mapping,
            ActionForm     form,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
  DynaValidatorForm dyna = (DynaValidatorForm) form;
  String identifier = (String) request.getParameter("id");
  ApplicationDTO app =  manager.getApplication(identifier);
  dyna.set("firstName",app.getFirstName());
  return (mapping.findForward("application.success"));      
}
```

The form bean looks like:

```
<form-bean name="ApplicationForm" type="struts.ApplicationForm">      
    <form-property name="id" type="java.lang.String" initial="0" />
    <form-property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String" />
    ...
    ..
    .
</form-bean>
```

ApplicationForm extends DynaValidatorForm and it does some validation.

How do I access a struts form property value inside my jsp.

```
<html:text property="firstName" styleId="firstName" value="TODO Add code to access the form property fistName END TODO"/>
```

## SOLUTION

user the *name* attribute within the *html:text* tag. Name attribute specifies the name of an object (in any scope) whose field, specified by the property attribute will be used to populate this control with data. Example:

```
<html:text property="firstName" styleId="firstName" name="ApplicationForm"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to access properties in Dynamic ActionForm Beans if you want a plain text output:

```
<bean:write name="ApplicationForm" property="firstName"/>
```